# Convert XClarity Controller on Lenovo server into usual network adapter

Tags: networking

I have a Lenovo server with XClarity Controller on it. Visually it looks like a usual network port, but it does not work in that way and is not listed in network adapters (`ip a`). Is there a way I can convert it and use it as just additional network adapter? OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you cannot. It's not a matter of drivers or compatibility – the port is not even attached to the server.

While it *is* a network port, it's attached to a separate "Management Controller" that coexists within the same server chassis but is essentially a fully separate computer, with its own CPU and OS.

There are mechanisms for a server and its BMC to share an Ethernet port, but they are only implemented for the opposite situation (sharing a *normal* port with the BMC) as the goal is to save on parts at the cost of various downsides.

If the server *does* have a dedicated BMC port, then the sharing mechanism is not used because the whole point of adding the extra port was to have it dedicated.

Comment: thanks, now it is clear why I can not see it.